# Adding a link to comparison page in Add-to-compare confirmation

Tags: template, magento-1, controllers, messages, compare

Is it possible to add a link to the comparison page from within the confirmation that an item has been added to the compare list?

The `addAction()` function in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php` is where the success message is generated. I tried adding some code in there to create the link to the compare page but I got a fatal error.

Answer (score 2):

Quick dirty fix.
at about line 93
`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php`

I added:

```
if ($product->getId()/* && !$product->isSuper()*/) {
//$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/product_compare');
$lin1= '<script type="text/javascript">';
$lin2 = "decorateList('compare-items')</script>";
$lin3 = '<a href="#"onclick="popWin(';
$lin4 = "'".Mage::getUrl('catalog/product_compare/index');
$lin5 = "','compare','top:0,left:0,width=820,height=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')";
$lin6 = '" >View compared products. </a>';
$house = $lin1.$lin2.$lin3.$lin4.$lin5.$lin6;
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_compare_list')->addProduct($product);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addSuccess(
    $this->__('The product %s has been added to comparison list. %s', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()), $house)
```

I'm running magento version 1.9.2.1

Comment: Wow perfect, just what I was looking for. Great job men

Answer (score 1):

The add action has the event `catalog_product_compare_add_product` which passes in the product object.

What you could do here is listen to this event and add a message to the session containing the url to the compare page.

Try using the following to get the url.

```
Mage::getUrl('catalog/product_compare/index');
```